# prevent old password prompt

Tags: password

Is there a way to prevent `Old Password:` ?

specifically when logged in when a user types `passwd` to change his or her password the first prompt is `Old Password:` followed by `New Password` then typically `Reenter New Password:`

or when doing `smbpasswd`

**is there a way to do away with the `Old Password:` prompt in Linux for the various mechanisms where it is used?**

I am most interested in doing it for `smbpasswd` first, then for `passwd` if possible.

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is imposed for non-root users in the utilities themselves, for example [in `smbpasswd`](https://git.samba.org/?p=samba.git;a=blob;f=source3/utils/smbpasswd.c;h=3136de6a23dd44ed05f5757c68a64e5914ebb53e;hb=HEAD#l573) and [in `passwd`](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/src/passwd.c#L240).

The only way to skip this is to change the source code, deal with the fallout (the protocols involved may require the old password, I haven’t checked), and rebuild.

I imagine you know the reason for this requirement: it helps prevent other people changing your password if you leave your system unlocked, or if they gain access to your account in some other way.